# Set System date and time using C++ in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, datetime

I am in the middle of developing a cross platform application that changes the system date and time to a specified value. I have completed the part for `Windows`.

How can I set the system date and time from a `C++` program in `Linux`? I am looking for a function similar to `SetSystemTime(SYSTEMTIME &x)`.

As far as I understood `settimeofday()` does nothing with the date and I am not sure about the usage of function `stime()`. I hope `mktime()` has nothing to do with my need.

Can anybody help me.

Comment: You should not set it in your program. You should configure your Linux system to use existing tools.

Comment: You should edit your question to explain why you cannot set the usual Linux time related services. I see no practical reason to call  `settimeofday` on a Linux laptop (because you should use NTP....)

Comment: What is the purpose of your application? Every OS is managing time (e.g. using NTP) much better than your attempted solution, and provides OS specific ways to do that. So I believe your app is useless or dangerous

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You understand wrongly. [settimeofday(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/settimeofday.2.html) is setting the [Epoch time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). which is both date and time. Read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html)

So you if you start from a string expressing a date, convert that string with [strptime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html) to a `struct tm` then convert that to a Unix time with [mktime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mktime.3.html) then feed that to `settimeofday` (i.e. the `tv_sec` field).

However, `settimeofday` requires root privilege and I believe you usually should avoid calling it (at least on usual, [Internet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet)-connected, computers). Better set some [NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) client service on your Linux PC (e.g.  run [ntpd](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/basic-ntp-config.html) or [chrony](http://chrony.tuxfamily.org/) and more generally read the sysadmin chapter on [keeping time](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/keeping-time.html)...). See also [adjtimex(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/adjtimex.2.html)

BTW, changing abruptly the system time on a [multi-tasking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_multitasking) system -like Linux or Windows- is a very dangerous operation (since it will upset and disturb a lot of system tasks depending or using the time). There are few good reasons to do that (it is a very bad idea in general). If you do that, do that with very few programs & services running (e.g. [single user mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_user_mode) Linux). You should not do that in ordinary application code.

Comment: Read the documentation, it is well explained. But I believe you are wrong in calling `settimeofday` in the first place.

Comment: Do you mean it is not the proper way to change system date and time? If so what else?

Comment: You should not change system date & time. You should have it correctly set and configured, using NTP... Follow the links I gave you.

Comment: Thank you.. Will let you know the result

Comment: yea, It gives me `EPERM` error. So I need to acquire root permission it seems. How can I grant it now?

Comment: Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and learn about [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid). Tip: **you are on the wrong track**. There is no good reason to code such a "portable" application in the first place, since time is well managed inside OS

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch So I may be in a similar situation.  I have an autopilot with GPS time that I would like to sync an onboard linux computer (Jetson TK1). The offset is calculated using an ntp style algorithm, but the autopilot itself doesn't support ntp.  Once I calculate the offset how do I adjust it?  The ntp user group suggested `adjtime` which I think is good, but for the initial jamsync, is `settimeofday` the best way?

Comment: I am doing a similar thing where I receive time information from a gps unit and need to update the system time to it.  The unit doesn't support ntp.

Comment: I really do not like this answer. Even though it is true that the documentation is obvious about how to actually call the function, this is stackoverflow a QA of code, so saying RTFA, you should not do this, is a disservice. As pointed in the comments there are embedded systems where this is perfectly legitimate to do and scaring people away from it in favor of the huge thing which is to set an run an ntp service in an embedded server is unfriendly.

Comment: @PauloNeves Exactly! Using embedded/portable handhelds w/o access to network in a remote factory site is a prime example of a scenario in which  you need to set time from an battery powered RTC.

Comment: `gettimeofday` is now [obsoleted by posix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69582757/1614903). I did not find anything about `settimeofday`. But see @parsley72 answer below for an example of the replacement by `clock_settime` https://stackoverflow.com/a/66894317/1614903

Answer (score 8):

I write this piece of code to set Date and Time under Linux.

```
#include <time.h>

struct tm time = { 0 };

time.tm_year = Year - 1900;
time.tm_mon  = Month - 1;
time.tm_mday = Day;
time.tm_hour = Hour;
time.tm_min  = Minute;
time.tm_sec  = Second;

if (time.tm_year < 0)
{
    time.tm_year = 0;
}

time_t t = mktime(&time);

if (t != (time_t) -1)
{
    stime(&t);
}
```

Note that `stime` requires `root` privileges.

Comment: The obsolete function stime is no longer available to newly linked
  binaries, and its declaration has been removed from <time.h>.
  Programs that set the system time should use clock_settime instead.

Comment: `mktime(&time)` uses `struct tm` as if it was _local_ time.  `time.tm_isdst = -1;`, else the time set will be an hour off half of the year.

Answer (score 3):

Example using `clock_settime` instead of `stime` since, as [Mehmet Fide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28314543/set-system-date-and-time-using-c-in-linux#comment117080473_46220529) pointed out, `stime` is now [deprecated](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stime.2.html#DESCRIPTION). I like the reference code from [Converting between timespec & std::chrono](https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2019/01/31/converting-between-timespec-stdchrono/) for this:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <chrono>

using std::chrono; // for example brevity

constexpr timespec timepointToTimespec(
    time_point<system_clock, nanoseconds> tp)
{
    auto secs = time_point_cast<seconds>(tp);
    auto ns = time_point_cast<nanoseconds>(tp) -
             time_point_cast<nanoseconds>(secs);

    return timespec{secs.time_since_epoch().count(), ns.count()};
}

const char* timePointToChar(
    const time_point<system_clock, nanoseconds>& tp) {
    time_t ttp = system_clock::to_time_t(tp);
    return ctime(&ttp);
}

const time_point system_time = system_clock::now();
cout << "System time = " << timePointToChar(system_time) << endl;

const timespec ts = timepointToTimespec(system_time);
clock_settime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
```