# What is the reason for deprecating/obsoleting certain Linux time APIs?

Tags: c, linux, posix

Linux has a number of APIs that can be used to set system time: we can use `time()`, `gettimeofday()`,`clock_gettime()` to get the time, and we can use`stime()`, `settimeofday()`,`clock_settime()` to set the time.

However, I noticed that some of these APIs are marked as "deprecated" or "obsolete". I couldn't find the reason behind this deprecation. Specifically:

Why is `stime()` deprecated ([source](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stime.2.html)) but not `time()`? `gettimeofday()` offers higher resolution than `time()`, but the former rather than the latter was declared "obsolete" ([source](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html)).

What are the reasons for these decisions?

Comment: The Linux main API is based on [the POSIX standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) which have evolved over the years. These functions are taken directly from the POSIX specification which have marked them as obsolete. [The POSIX reference site](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) might have some explanations about why these functions have been made obsolete.

Comment: this question is discussed at [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412305/839601)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These APIs have been declared as "obsolete" for the usual reasons: they are old, not secure, not portable, have unspecified/undefined behavior, have tricky edge cases, better alternatives exist, etc.

Deprecation of APIs in Linux is generally done on a case-by-case basis; there is no general rule.

---

> Why is `stime()` deprecated…

It's a non-standard function from `SVr4` that nobody uses (on Linux). You should use `clock_settime` instead in every case.

> …but not `time()`?

`time()` is a super standard function available everywhere, as it's the part of the [C language standard](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.23.2.4). It will be used until the end of... time!

> `gettimeofday()` offers higher resolution than `time()`, but the former rather than the latter was declared "obsolete"

[`gettimeofday()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gettimeofday.html) is a POSIX function, and POSIX standardized existing practices. After some time (POSIX Issue 7) `clock_gettime()` was invented with greater resolution and to be more portable. Because a better and safer interface exists, POSIX noted that `gettimeofday()` is obsolesced. I think the note is pretty self-explanatory to a developer:

> APPLICATION USAGE
>
> Applications should use the clock_gettime() function instead of the obsolescent gettimeofday() function.

---

In general, to find out why a particular API was deprecated, research about particular project history. Source code repositories offer commit history, standards, like POSIX or the C standard, come with "rationale", a separate document or included with the document, that explain the decisions.

For example, you can find out about `stime()` deprecation in glibc from [this commit](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/commit/12cbde1dae6fa4a9a792b64564c7e0debf7544cc):

```
* The obsolete function stime is no longer available to newly linked
  binaries and it has been removed from <time.h> header.  This function
  has been deprecated in favor of clock_settime.
```