# How can I change the values of the system clock using C++?

Tags: c++, windows

I've been trying to figure out how to use the system clock for a class project. The goal is to display the system's current time, then through inputs of 1-4 add one hour, minute, or second, then display the clock again. I think I have the basic framework down but I cannot figure out how to display the system time correctly as well as change the time itself. I have researched a few of the libraries to use and it gets pretty confusing with the pointers and the way it also always prints the date as well. I'm still new to C++ so my code is not the best especially when formatting the functions for the displays. Any help is appreciated.

When I run the program I want to print the local time from the PC it is running on, then receive input from the user (keystroke 1 - 4), then print the new time again. I don't want to actually change the time on my PC. For example say the current local time of my computer is 08:22:14, which will print to the screen. I wait any amount of time before I input selection 2. The new time will print 08:23:14.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <time.h>       /* time_t, struct tm, time, localtime */
#include <iostream> // std::cout, std::endl
#include <iomanip>  // std::setfill, std::setw
#include <stdlib.h> // system(CLS);
#include <Windows.h>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int DisplayClocks(int time) {   // Function to write both clocks to screen  

    std::cout << std::setfill('*') << std::setw(26) << "     " << std::setfill('*') << std::setw(26) << " " << endl;    // First line of "*"
    std::cout << "*" << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(16) << "12 Hour Clock" << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(4) << "  *" << "     "
        << "*" << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(18) << "24 Hour Clock" << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(6) << "  *" << endl;
        // 12 hour clock
    std::cout << "*" << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(6) << " " << time << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(6) << "  *" << "     "
        // 24 hour clock
        << "*" << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(8) << " " << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(8) << "  *" << endl;
    std::cout << std::setfill('*') << std::setw(26) << "     " << std::setfill('*') << std::setw(26) << " " << endl;    // Last line of "*"
        
    return 0;

}

void DisplaySelection() {   // Function to display selection menu for user
    
    std::cout << std::setfill('*') << std::setw(26) << " " << endl;
    std::cout << "*" << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(19) << "1 - Add One Hour" << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(5) << "  *" << endl;
    std::cout << "*" << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(20) << "2 - Add One Minute" << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(4) << "  *" << endl;
    std::cout << "*" << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(20) << "3 - Add One Second" << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(4) << "  *" << endl;
    std::cout << "*" << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(19) << "4 - Exit Program" << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(5) << "  *" << endl;
    std::cout << std::setfill('*') << std::setw(26) << " " << endl;

}

void main()
{
    
    time_t now = time(0);
    system("CLS");
    
    string userVal;
    
    DisplayClocks(now); // Call displayClocks on program start
    DisplaySelection(); // Call DisplaySelection after display clocks
    cin >> userVal; // Take user input to modify clock display

    while (!( userVal == "Exit")) {
        // FIX ME: Add functionality to clear screen every second
        // FIX ME: Add displayClock to relevant if statements
        if (userVal == "1") {
            // Add One Hour to Clocks
            // FIX ME: Functionality for Displaying 12 and 24 hour clocks
            system("CLS"); // Clear screen test... working...
            DisplayClocks(now); // Call displayClocks on program start
            DisplaySelection(); // Call DisplaySelection after display clocks
            cout << "1" << endl;
            cin >> userVal;
        }

        else if (userVal == "2") {
            // Add One Minute to Clocks
            // FIX ME: Functionality for Displaying 12 and 24 hour clocks
            system("CLS"); // Clear screen test... working...
            DisplayClocks(now); // Call displayClocks on program start
            DisplaySelection(); // Call DisplaySelection after display clocks
            cout << "2" << endl;
            cin >> userVal;
        }

        else if (userVal == "3") {
            // Add One Second to Clocks
            // FIX ME: Functionality for Displaying 12 and 24 hour clocks
            system("CLS"); // Clear screen test... working...
            DisplayClocks(now); // Call displayClocks on program start
            DisplaySelection(); // Call DisplaySelection after display clocks
            cout << "3" << endl;
            cin >> userVal;
        }

        else if (userVal == "4") {
            // Exit Program
            // FIX ME: Functionality for Displaying 12 and 24 hour clocks
            cout << "Program Ended" << endl;
            break;
        }

        else{
            // Prompt user to input correct selection when not userVal ! (1-4)
            system("CLS"); // Clear screen test... working...
            DisplayClocks(now); 
            DisplaySelection();
            cout << "Error: Enter a selection 1 - 4." << endl;
            cin >> userVal;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28314543/set-system-date-and-time-using-c-in-linux if you mean to actuall change the system clock, is that what you mean

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but each branch in your code have the same code, code which could be be moved to after the checks before the loop iterates (or be put first inside the loop). The less copy-pasted code you have, the easier it will be to continue develop and maintain your applications.

Comment: And considering some parts of the code (the `system("CLS")` and most importantly the inclusion of `<windows.h>`) I took the liberty to add the `windows` tag to your question. Things like updating the system clock is not part of standard C++, it's platform dependent. If you add platform information in your searches you should quite quickly find examples and tutorials on how to do what you want.

Comment: is it the actual system time u want to change, or is it that you want show an offset from them system time? if the latter, then you just need to get a current time and then whenever user adds or deletes something modify that value.

Comment: Sorry for the miscommunication here. When I run the program I want to print the local time from the PC it is running on, then receive input from the user (keystroke 1 - 4), then print the new time again. I don't want to actually change the time on my PC. For example say the current local time of my computer is 08:22:14, which will print to the screen. I wait any amount of time before I input selection 2. The new time will print 08:23:14.

Comment: Then get the current time from [the system clock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock), and add a suitable [duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration).

Answer (score 0):

When you ask "How can I change ***SYSTEM*** <anything> in C++?", the keyword is "system".

It means that it's platform-dependent, so it needs a ***SYSTEM*** call - and I'm not speaking about the `system` function, but a call to your operating system's API, Win32 in your case. And a lot of these functions will requires elevation to work, on both Windows and Linux...
Unfortunately for you, changing system date and time is such a function, on both OS, and it isn't allowed to call it with a standard account.

Also, it has nothing related with C++, in fact. On Windows, you'll need to call `SetSystemTime`, and it's not a C++ feature but a function of `kernel32.dll` imported through `sysinfoapi.h` header (found in Windows SDK).
You'll get exactly the same answer in near any programming language: *"Do a system call to `SetSystemTime`"*.